# retrofit2 okhttp3 android multipart socket tomeout error

Tags: android, sockets, timeout, retrofit2, okhttp

I am trying to upload a file with Retrofit 2 and it is giving me 
"socket timed connection out" error every time even after adding the timeout limits. Any suggestions on how to fix this -

My Rest client setup -

```
private static void setupRestClient() {
        if(LoginToken != null && !LoginToken.isEmpty()) {
            OkHttpClient httpClient = new OkHttpClient();
            httpClient.interceptors().add(new Interceptor() {
                @Override
                public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
                    Request request = chain.request().newBuilder().addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer "+ LoginToken).build();
                    return chain.proceed(request);
                }
            });
            Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .client(httpClient)
                    .build();
            REST_CLIENT = retrofit.create(Api.class);
        } else {
            Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
            REST_CLIENT = retrofit.create(Api.class);
        }
    }
```

After reading several answers on SO, I also tried -

```
OkHttpClient httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                    .connectTimeout(12, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                    .readTimeout(12, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                    .writeTimeout(12, TimeUnit.MINUTES).build();
```

But, got the same timeout error with this also. 
File upload starting intent -

```
Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        if(takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(EduwiserMainActivity.this.getPackageManager()) != null){
            File photoFile = null;
            try{
                photoFile = createImageFile();
                takePictureIntent.putExtra("PhotoPath", mCM);
            } catch(IOException ex){
                Log.e("Error:", "Image file creation failed", ex);
            }
            if(photoFile != null){
                dfCM = "file:" + photoFile.getAbsolutePath();
                mCM = photoFile.getPath();
                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
            } else {
                takePictureIntent = null;
            }
        }
        Intent contentSelectionIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        contentSelectionIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
        contentSelectionIntent.setType("image/*");
        Intent[] intentArray;
        if(takePictureIntent != null){
            intentArray = new Intent[]{takePictureIntent};
        } else {
            intentArray = new Intent[0];
        }

        Intent chooserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CHOOSER);
        chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, contentSelectionIntent);
        chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "Choose image");
        chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, intentArray);
        startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, FCR);
```

on intent activity result -

```
if(requestCode == FCR && resultCode == -1){
            try {
                File file = null;
                String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
                String localPath = mCM != null && !mCM.isEmpty() ? mCM.replace("file:", "") : null;
                if(data == null || data.getData() == null){
                    //Capture Photo if no image available
                    if(localPath != null){
                        file = new File(localPath);
                    }
                } else {
                    String dataString = data.getDataString();
                    if(dataString != null){
                        try {
                            file = new File(PathUtil.getPath(this, Uri.parse(dataString)));
                        } catch (Exception e){
                            Log.e("error", e.toString());
                        }
                    }
                }
                final File newFile = file;
                defaultPd = new ProgressDialog(EduwiserMainActivity.this);
                if(token != null && !token.isEmpty() && newFile != null && documentUploadFileType != null && !documentUploadFileType.isEmpty()){
                    try {
                        if(defaultPd != null && !defaultPd.isShowing()) {
                            defaultPd.show();
                            defaultPd.setMessage("Uploading file...");
                        }
                        RequestBody requestFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), newFile);
                        MultipartBody.Part body = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData(!Objects.equals(documentUploadFileType, "profile") ? documentUploadFileType + "_file":
                                documentUploadFileType, documentUploadFileType + ".jpg", requestFile);
                        documentUploadFileType = null;
                        Call<LocalAuthResponse> call = RestClient.get(getApplicationContext()).uploadTeacherDocuments("Bearer " + token, body);
                        call.enqueue(new Callback<LocalAuthResponse>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(Call<LocalAuthResponse> call, Response<LocalAuthResponse> response) {
                                try {
                                    if(defaultPd != null && defaultPd.isShowing()) {
                                        defaultPd.dismiss();
                                    }
                                } catch (Exception e){}
                                try {
                                    if(response.body() != null && response.body().getSuccess()) {
                                        mWebView.evaluateJavascript("var event = new CustomEvent('refresh_userdata');document.dispatchEvent(event);", null);
                                    }
                                } catch (Exception e){
//                                mWebView.evaluateJavascript("var event = new CustomEvent('refresh_userdata');document.dispatchEvent(event);", null);
                                }
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(Call<LocalAuthResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error Uploading Documents. Please try again.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                try {
                                    if(defaultPd != null && defaultPd.isShowing()) {
                                        defaultPd.dismiss();
                                    }
                                } catch (Exception e){}
                                mWebView.evaluateJavascript("var event = new CustomEvent('fail_attachment');document.dispatchEvent(event);", null);
                            }
                        });
                    } catch (Exception e){
                        Log.e("error", e.toString());
                    }
                }
            } catch(Exception e){
                Log.e("error", e.toString());
            }
        } else if(requestCode == FCR){
            mWebView.evaluateJavascript("var event = new CustomEvent('fail_attachment');document.dispatchEvent(event);", null);
        }
```

Now, I am getting "socket timeout error exception" in the onFailure block.
Now, this might be an entirely different error which is throwing socket timeout exception or this is actually because of timeout. 
Either way, any suggestions as to how to debug or fix this ?

Comment: Firstly, just for good stackoverflow questions, please include the stacktrace so it's clear at what point it's failing.

Comment: I'd also try, making the same request running in your IDE instead of on mobile, seeing whether it's device/network related.  And try some similar requests from your mobile also that don't involve the file uploads.  e.g. GET "/robots.txt"

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are getting the valid image file so lets come to upload section

```
@Multipart
@POST("api/image/upload")
Call<String> imageUpload(@Part MultipartBody.Part image, @Part("name") RequestBody name);
```

and the upload function

```
    private void uploadImage(File file) {
    try {
        if (file.exists()) {
            RequestBody reqFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), file);
            MultipartBody.Part body = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("upload", file.getName(), reqFile);
            RequestBody name = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), "upload_test");
            RestClient.getService().imageUpload(body, name).enqueue(new Callback<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<String> call, @NonNull final Response<String> response) {
                    newImageUrl = response.body();
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<String> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {

                }
            });
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        toast("Please try again");
    }
}
```

and my retrofit looks like this

```
new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(ConfigHelper.DataServiceUrl)
                .addConverterFactory(converterFactory)
                .client(client
                        .addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
                            public Response intercept(@NonNull Chain chain) throws IOException {
                                return chain.proceed(chain.request().newBuilder().addHeader("access_key", finalToken).build());
                            }
                        })
                        .addInterceptor(logging)
                        .build()).build();
```

Happy Coding :)